# Row/column-level security in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks

Are there any hooks in Entity Framework 6 that allows implementing row-level security / column level security? 
Because in NHibernate 3 & 4, I can hook in SQL and generate filter for row-level security / column level security.

Thanks,

Comment: Still no solution for this question ?

Comment: @AramKocharyan See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38909369/4468078 for a possible solution

Comment: @RYoda thanks for the response. I have developed a solution for it. ( It is still in development ) https://github.com/arkoc/EntityFramework.Guardian