# Entity Framework Core Row Level Security using SESSION_CONTEXT

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am writing a multi-tenant application using Row Level Security using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework 7 (Core). 
Since my database is hosted on Microsoft SQL Server, I have used [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx) method to enforce RLS.

Now all I need is to set desired tenant_id in the SESSION_CONTEXT.

First problem I faced was to run a stored procedure using EF7. A solution seems to be:

```
var resp = context.Set<SessionVars>().FromSql(
          "EXECUTE sp_set_session_context @key = N'my_tenant', @value = {0};
           SELECT * FROM mySessionVars", desiredTenant).ToList();
```

Using the above command I can clearly see that the SESSION_CONTEXT is successfully set. Now I expect to see that the next queries on the same context are filtered according to the tenant I set in SESSION_CONTEXT.

```
int visibleRows = context.MyModel.ToList().Count;
```

Unfortunately the results are not as expected. It behaves like the rows were retrieved before SESSION_CONTEXT was set.

Is this caused by the Eager Loading of EF7? IS EF7 using cashed data?
How can I overcome this?

I expect to be able to set any value I want for the SESSION_CONTEXT and this to be hold in the context until changed or until connection is closed.

Comment: A couple of blogs show a different approach, http://craigpickles.com/row-level-security-in-azure-sql-with-entity-framework/ not sure if that is helpful or not. but thought i would share.

Comment: As of Entity Framework Core 2.0, Global Query Filters is a better solution to Row Level Security instead of using the database.  http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/08/ef-core-global-query-filters/

Comment: @Greg0 Query filters are nice feature, but I prefer injecting session context so that the server will validate the tenancy.

Answer (score 4):

I was abble to found an answer mysels by reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456849.aspx),

> EF6 and future versions we have taken the approach that if the calling
>   code chooses to open the connection by calling
>   context.Database.Connection.Open() then it has a good reason for doing
>   so and the framework will assume that it wants control over opening
>   and closing of the connection and will no longer close the connection
>   automatically.

The solution is to open the connection before executing any EF command.

```
context.Database.Connection.Open();
```

Comment: How did it go with this?  I am looking to do the very same thing.

Comment: Or first inject your context and then retreive your session vars from the client ?